# jQuery Leaflet Find Feature Geometry Type Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I need get feature geometry type, I can get feature object on leaflet like this

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    console.log(layer);
});
```

This response is like in this screenshot:

[image: layer object]

But when I try this

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    console.log(layer.feature.geometry);
});
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geometry')

How can I get type prop in geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Only imported layers over `L.geoJSON(geojson)` are having the `feature` property.

But you can generate the GeoJSON of every layer:

```
var geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
console.log(geojson.feature.geometry);
```

Maybe the layer is also a LayerGroup then you need first to loop through all `features`:

```
if(layer instanceof L.LayerGroup){
   layer.toGeoJSON().features.forEach((feature)=>{
      console.log(feature.geometry);
   });
} else {
   var geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
   console.log(geojson.feature.geometry);
}
```

Comment: it giving : layer.toGeoJSON is not a function